# Is there a measure that account for the the location diversity and trajectory distance of agents?

Tags: distance, trajectory

I am currently working on project to assess the success of musicians. For each musician I know when and where (coordinates,city,county) they performed in a gig. I assume a successful musician is the one who travel get frequent bookings in diverse countries. I like to account for the number of gigs, and number of cities and countries. For example, the musician A only performs only in US might have a longer travel distance, compare to the musician B who performed in multiple countries in Europe.

So far I thought about computing the total travel distance by summing up the distance between the cities for consecutive gigs. This doesn't account for the location diversity as one artists can move frequently between few cities.

I also thought to create a polygon of a musician trajectory and use the "area" of the polygon as the success measure. However, it seems duplicated cities create a holes in the polygon and reduce the area. For example in the following example I was hoping `geom1` (3.05402) have a higher area than `geom2` (8.695). When I remove the the second visit to Cologne in the `geom1` the area changes to 11.87. If I remove the duplicated from each trajectory I can not control for the number of gigs any more.

```
geom1 = Polygon([city_points_obj['cologne'],city_points_obj['berlin'],city_points_obj['paris'],city_points_obj['cologne'],city_points_obj['milan']]) #area: 3.05402


geom2 = Polygon([city_points_obj['cologne'],city_points_obj['berlin'],city_points_obj['stuttgart'],city_points_obj['cologne']]) #area: 8.6952
```

Since I have a very limited (almost none) education on in GIS analysis, I though there might be some other measures that I'm not aware of, or get some suggestions from experts.

Comment: Just add up the visitors to each gig.

Comment: I think you may need to get more education in spatial analysis before attempting to model this.  Area seems to be a poor way to model point locations. Building a heatmap of location gig-days is probably the best option you have for areal representation, possibly weighted by population and attendance, but this isn't a GIS problem yet.

Comment: It might not be an ideal measure. For example bands from Quebec will likely go to France to give a few shows. It is far away, but since people speak the same language they will have more attendance than if they go sing in Ontario or in the USA even though we share a border.

Comment: @Erik I wish I had that information.

Comment: @Vince thanks for the tip. Can you elaborate more on the heatmap idea. or point me to a relevant example? at the end, I need a number for each year of musician's career.